# Failed to install PyGObject in heroku

Tags: python, linux, heroku, pip, pygobject

I have struggled last day to install `PyGObject` in a python project on Heroku, but with no luck.

I have also made an empty Heroku app, but I couldn't install it there either. (tried with pip from inside heroku bash, or in requirments file, always the same error: https://pastebin.com/RcJvC9MJ)

I have also tried to install it via the apt buildpack, but it doesn't seems to install. My apt file contained the packages from pygobject [getting started](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) `python3-gi python3-gi-cairo gir1.2-gtk-3.0`. During the build phase, they seem to install fine, but the app doesn't see pygobject.

When trying to install with pip, it gives the following error: https://pastebin.com/RcJvC9MJ. I have tried to manually install pkg-config (by adding it in the Aptfile), but then another package is not found (https://pastebin.com/SuVR25Ei). I have then repeated the process (by adding the new package to the Aptfile). I have spent some time just adding more packages to the aptfile, and now it has ~300 of packages (generated using apt dependencies), but still no luck. (Everytime there is some package that needs to be installed)

I have also tried to remove '~/.cache/pip', as in [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/cdl8ap/i_am_having_trouble_installing_pygobject_using/), but it doesn't work.

I have also tried using various python/pip version.

Does anyone has any clue on how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered similar problems with heroku previously

`sudo apt install python3-gi python3-gi-cairo gir1.2-gtk-3.0` seems to be the suggested way og installing PyGObject.

This solution is most likely to work, but if that's not helpful either, my best suggestion is to use Docker.

Create a `heroku.yml` file and a `Dockerfile`.
This [heroku.yml](https://github.com/FalseDev/braincabin-dj/blob/master/heroku.yml) file can be used as an example.

If you use **heroku CLI** you can run `heroku stack:set container` to change your stack to docker containers.

Also I'd suggest letting heroku build the image using the specification in the `heroku.yml` file instead of pushing an image into the container registry.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: I am not familiar with docker, but I also thought that it could be a potential solution. i will try it in te coming days.

Answer (score 0):

(should be a comment)
same issue :(, I keep getting this error:

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyGObject
```

I originally had this issue with an app I was trying to deploy so I ended up making a dummy app to test it out, but nope, same results.

I'm not too sure myself how to work around this :(.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31312864)